# Microsoft Delta Query not returing openextension defined while creating event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am working on a usecase by integrating microsoft graph api to create calendar events.
Below is the payload while creating an Outlook calendar event.

```
{
  "subject": "Test This Payload Again 2",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does late morning work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2019-12-17T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2019-12-18T14:00:56.718",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  extensions:[
  {
    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName" : "CALENDAR CTX",
    "ctxType" : "CONTEXT",
    "ctxId" : "12345"
  }
  ],
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
     {
           "id":"String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00040ec6ac6e} Name CONTEXT",
           "value":"12345"
     }
  ]
}
```

I have a usecase to add custom properties in the event and take some action during incremental sync using Delta Query. I tried to add `extensions` as well as `singleValueExtendedProperties` while creating, but not able to get the same payload (with extensions/singleValueExtendedProperties) during incremental sync using Delta Query. I am just getting the event resource.

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Anything on this ?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not yet supported by delta queries, there is an existing [uservoice entry](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/31791508-allow-ms-graph-api-messages-delta-to-include-sing) that you can vote for to help prioritize the ask. It will also keep you posted of any decision/progress.